# Recode matrix values with dplyr based on look-up table

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have a matrix with numerous cases and corresponding answers from a questionnaire. The strongly reduced example below (raw_responses) contains the answers of 5 persons to 5 items. Let us assume that these are multiple choice items with 4 possible answers each. If the item was not processed, the person received the code 9.

```
raw_responses <- data.frame('id' = 1:10,
                            'item_1' =  sample(c(1:4,9), 10, replace = TRUE),
                            'item_2' =  sample(c(1:4,9), 10, replace = TRUE),
                            'item_3' =  sample(c(1:4,9), 10, replace = TRUE),
                            'item_4' =  sample(c(1:4,9), 10, replace = TRUE),
                            'item_5' =  sample(c(1:4,9), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

The correct answers are stored in a separate table that reflects the entire test design. Below again a strongly reduced variant (design) with only item names and the corresponding correct answers.

```
design <- data.frame('item' = c('item_1','item_2','item_3','item_4','item_5'),
                     'key' = sample(1:4, 5, replace = TRUE))
```

Finally, the goal is a table with scored answers. A correct answer is coded with 1, a wrong one with 0 and an "empty" answer with 99. This works for example with the for loop below.

```
scored_responses <- raw_responses
for(item in colnames(raw_responses)[2:6]) {
  scored_responses[, item] <- ifelse(scored_responses[, item] == design[design$item == item, 'key'], 1, 
                                     ifelse(scored_responses[, item] == 9, 99, 0))
}
```

However, I was wondering if this would work with a more efficient variant with dplyr (including case_when) and possibly purr. Especially because the very extensive answer table is cleaned up with the help of a longer dplyr-pipe, it would be an advantage if the scoring could be built in there.

I thank you in advance for all ideas and hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the data in long format, join, recode the values and get the data back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

raw_responses %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = 'item') %>%
  left_join(design, by = 'item') %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(value == 9 ~ 99,
                           value == key ~ 1, 
                           TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'item')

# A tibble: 10 x 6
#      id item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4 item_5
#   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1     99     99      1      0      0
# 2     2     99     99     99      0      0
# 3     3      1     99      0     99     99
# 4     4      0      1      1     99      1
# 5     5     99      0      1      0      1
# 6     6      0      1      0      0      1
# 7     7      0      0      0      1     99
# 8     8      1     99      0      0      0
# 9     9      0     99     99      0      1
#10    10     99      1     99      1      0
```

---

Another approach without getting data into wide format is to use `map2_dfc` from `purrr` :

```
library(purrr)
map2_dfc(raw_responses[-1], design$key, ~case_when(.x == 9 ~ 99,
                                                   .x == .y ~ 1, 
                                                   TRUE ~ 0))
```

However, for this answer to work we need to ensure that column names in `raw_responses` and `design$item` are in the same order. In this example, they are already in the same order however, in the real data if they are not we can achieve it by doing :

```
raw_responses[-1] <- raw_responses[-1][design$key]
```